# What is the motivation of the graph filter in the Graph Convolutional Networks?

Tags: graph-theory, convolution

What is the motivation of the graph filter in the Graph Convolutional Networks? For example [in the paper](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=SJU4ayYgl)

In the Eq.~(3):  they perform the convolution the singal $x$ with $g_\theta$ as:

$g_\theta * x = U g_\theta U^Tx$.

What it the role of $g_\theta$ here?Thanks

As I know from [signal process](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/4723/what-is-the-physical-meaning-of-the-convolution-of-two-signals)
convolution means "reverse, shift, multiply and sum". And for graph, what is the intuition for convolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the graph filter make a role as localization the node with its neighborhoods. To make them share the properties with it. And nice paper recently explain this [trick](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.02046)